# how can I define per-instance resources for elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation, alarm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'd like to create an AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm resource for each instance that gets created in an elastic beanstalk auto scaling group. I presume I can do this via .ebextensions, but am unable to find a way to get a reference to the InstanceId when a new instance is created.

I'd prefer to create (and destroy) the alarm via .ebextensions Resources, rather than creating a script that runs on the instance and creates the alarm via AWS CLI.